# ¿Comó puedo hacer para que en un foreach (laravel) me pueda imprimir los resultados de dos variables, en vez de usar doblemente el foreach?

Tags: html5, laravel-blade

En el código siguiente muestro como obtengo las variables que es "empresa" y con las funciones de *laravel* complemento el "código", pero, ¿cómo puedo poner dos variables como si fuese una:  "empresa && establecimientos"?

```html
 <div class="container-fluid" id="secciones">
        <div class="row" style="cursor: pointer">
            @foreach ($empresas as $empresa)
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="card 1" onclick="verSeccion({{ $empresa->id }})">
                        <div class="card_image"> <img src="{{ asset('storage') . '/' . $empresa->foto_perfil }}" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="card_title title-white">
                            <p style="opacity: 90%; color:white;">
                                {{ $empresa->nom_empresa }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: no veas el foreach como la recuperación para una sola variable, sino como el recorrido de un objeto con N atributos, por lo que en ese mismo foreach puedes recuperar todo lo que necesitas. Agrega el código de la consulta del modelo, para formular el código ejemplo

Comment: Te paso una pregunta en inglés que podría ayudarte:  [Multiple variable pass in one Foreach loop in laravel blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751535/multiple-variable-pass-in-one-foreach-loop-in-laravel-blade/53752064)

Comment: ok, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya me quedo mas claro

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer esto:

```
{{ $empresa->nom_empresa." ".$empresa->establecimientos }}
```

o esto:

```
{{ $empresa->nom_empresa }} {{ $empresa->establecimientos }}
```

Comment: probare de las dos formas, a ver cual es la que me resulta validad, gracias